# Can I run ARCORE with the SM-G9500?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

When I run ARcore on my mobile phone with SM-G95000, the project will crash. Is my device not supported ARcore?

Comment: I'm checking the list of supported devices and it seems that the version 1.1 does not support the SM-g9500, I was almost sure that the version 1 did, but can't find the list from that date of supported devices, since it seems they have replace with each update. do you know if that model has been eliminated from the list? or never has been there?

Answer (score 7):

Try a modified version of the `arcore-client` which removes the check: https://github.com/tomthecarrot/arcore-for-all

> In your Android project, simply replace the Google-provided
>   arcore_client.aar with the one in this repo, and voilà! ARCore on any
>   Android device.
>
> Make sure to first install ARCore Service - "Preparing your Device"
>   section of Google's instructions
>   https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/getting-started

**EDIT:**
If you use such "hacked" versions, you have to expect a bad tracking performance since the devices have to be properly calibrated.

Answer (score 3):

I run ARCore on Samsung Galaxy S8+ SM-G955F which is not officially supported, so I believe that you can run too.

Prerequisite:

1. Read your Model Number from Settings. In my case SM-G955F.
2. Open ARCore sample project in AndroidStudio, open HelloArActivity.java and go to onCreate method.
3. Add Log here.

   ```
   if (!mSession.isSupported(mDefaultConfig)) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not support AR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Log.d(TAG, "Fingerprint=" + Build.FINGERPRINT);
       finish();
       return;
   }
   ```
4. Run this code and read fingerprint. In my case it contains

   dream2ltexx/dream2lte

Now go to ARCore folder.

1. Extract arcore-android-sdk-master/libraries/arcore_client.aar
2. Go to extracted folder and extract classes.jar
3. Edit /com/google/atap/tangoservice/SupportedDevices.class
   I use MidnightCommander in GNU/Linux system. Shortcut to edit is Shift+F3 then F4 then  find similar string to yours fingerprint. In my case it was "dreamltexx/dreamlte:7". I changed this string to "dream2ltexx/dream2lte"
4. Use 'jar' tool to zip back to classes.jar or use 'zip' and change extension to .jar.
5. Zip back all arcore_client and change extension to .aar
6. Replace aar library and rebuild in AndroidStudio.

In my case it works. Happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `SM-G9500` is one of the Samsung Galaxy S8 models that is not supported by the current developer preview release of ARCore.  Only the specific model numbers listed [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/#supported_devices) are currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Galaxy S8 (SM-G9500) was not supported by the developer preview release of ARCore but it's supported starting with version 1.0 (using 1.0 will fix your crash)
You can check the list of latest supported devices here: https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/#supported_devices
(even the Galaxy S7 is now supported)